# Non-blocking ConnectNamedPipe event not getting signaled

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, events, named-pipes

I am starting out with named pipes and need to use them for IPC between two local processes. I have both the server and client process using the pipe in nonblocking overlapped mode.

Everything works fine (the server successfully receives a string sent by the client) except that the event passed to ConnectNamedPipe() via the OVERLAPPED structure is not getting signaled as expected (signaled when a client connects).

While the server is blocked on the WaitForSingleObject() call the client process connected to the pipe, sent its data and terminated yet the event does not get signaled. What am I missing?

Server code:

```
HANDLE hPipe = ::CreateNamedPipeW(
    L"\\\\.\\pipe\\ThePipe",
    PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_NOWAIT,
    1,
    4096,
    4096,
    100,
    nullptr);

OVERLAPPED ov = {0};
ov.hEvent = ::CreateEventW(nullptr, TRUE, FALSE, nullptr);

BOOL retVal = ::ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, &ov);

if (retVal == 0)
{
    DWORD err = ::GetLastError();
    if (err == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
    {
        ::WaitForSingleObject(ov.hEvent, 30000);
    }
    if (err == ERROR_PIPE_LISTENING)
    {
        ::WaitForSingleObject(ov.hEvent, 30000);    // this blocks until time-out???
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it receive ERROR_IO_PENDING? (you'd better make this case easy to distinguish, or you have to attach to process and see where it waits)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't use (deprecated) `PIPE_NOWAIT` together with overlapped mode. `PIPE_NOWAIT` makes `ConnectNamedPipe` immediately return `ERROR_PIPE_LISTENING` if no client is connected; overlapped I/O just doesn't happen, and waiting for event is useless.

Either you set `PIPE_NOWAIT` and poll the pipe periodically until success, or you set `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` and use an event to check/wait for completion.

Comment: Fixed my problem. Thank you so much! Microsoft should really update the documentation on this.

Comment: From the MSDN page on CreateNamedPipe: "Note that nonblocking mode is supported for compatibility with Microsoft LAN Manager version 2.0 and should not be used to achieve asynchronous I/O with named pipes."

Comment: There are warnings about not using ConnectNamedPipe in asynchronous mode.  Instead an `OVERLAPPED` structure can be passed in to `ReadFile` to wait for reading.